# How could I make this code shorter?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I make this code shorter?

```
r = 11

Do While Not tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = "0"

    If tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 1, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 2, 2) Or _
        tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 3, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 4, 2) Or _
        tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 5, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 6, 2) Or _
        tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 7, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 8, 2) Or _
        tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 9, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 10, 2) Or _
        tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 11, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 12, 2) Or _
        tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 13, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 14, 2) Or _
        tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 15, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 16, 2) Or _
        tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 17, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 18, 2) Then

        MsgBox "Duplicate Record Found!"
        Exit Sub

    Else

        r = r + 1

    End If

Loop
```

Comment: Have you heard of for loop? http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

Comment: This is a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Using the `WorksheetFunction.CountIF` you can count the number of times a particular values in your case Range(r & "2) is repeated in a range and using that result we can compute if the value is duplicated.

```
r = 11

Do While Not tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = "0"
    IF WorksheetFunction.CountIF(tgtWSheet.Range("B" & r & ":S" & r),tgtWSheet.Range("B" & r)) > 1 Then

        MsgBox "Duplicate Record Found!"
        Exit Sub

    Else

        r = r + 1

    End If

Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `.Find()` method of "Range" object

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub main()

    Dim rowOffset As Long
    Dim tgtWSheet As Worksheet

    Set tgtWSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tgtW") '<== adapt to your needs

    With tgtWSheet.Cells(11, 2)
        Do While .Offset(rowOffset).Value <> "0"

            If .Offset(rowOffset + 1).Resize(18).Find(What:=.Offset(rowOffset), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then
                rowOffset = rowOffset + 1
            Else
                MsgBox "Duplicate Record Found!"
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Loop
    End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

With the use of a For cycle:

```
 r = 11

Do Until tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = "0"
    for i = 1 to 18
        If tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + i, 2) Then
            MsgBox "Duplicate Record Found!"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            r = r + 1
        End If
    next
Loop
```

Be careful though! The code stops at the first "0" encountered.

BONUS: `Do While Not` = `Do Until`